# How do I draw a new image without making a new UIImageView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have a character in an iPod Touch game I am making that moves around the screen.  That I have under control... However I want him able to shoot fireballs, and I don't want to have to make a new UIImageView for every fire ball he shoots.  I have the image and everything... I think i need to use quartz core or openGL ES, but I can't make sense of the apple documentation.

Comment: Chris Hanson... what did you edit of my question?

Comment: Chris removed the tags 'Xcode' and 'Objective-C' and added the tags 'cocoa-touch' and 'game-development'. Also, as an aside, you may want to have a quick look at the Cocos2D game engine that is open source and freely available for iPhone (and other platforms). You might find that this already does a lot of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: THANKYOU! so much... However, I can't seem to find out how to install the templates... any help?

Comment: There's a shell script that you can run to install the templates. It should be located in the Cocos2D folder and aptly named 'install-templates.sh'.

Comment: Do I open that with terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option would be to implement `drawRect` in your view, and draw the fireballs there.